# Conecta a la base de datos, no logra ingresar a la cuenta

Tags: php, html, mysqli, login

Logre que se conecte a la base de datos, pero al ingresar (login) dice que los datos ingresados son erróneos por más que los datos ingresados sean los correctos.

Agrego el formulario de registro donde realiza la acción de registrar los datos en la base de datos.

**Formulario para registrarse (create-account.php)**

```
<?php

include 'conn.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query to check if the email already exist
$checkEmail = "SELECT * FROM w_usuarios WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' ";

// Variable $result hold the connection data and the query
$result = $conn-> query($checkEmail);

// Variable $count hold the result of the query
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If count == 1 that means the email is already on the database
if ($count == 1) {
echo "<div class='alert alert-warning mt-4' role='alert'>
                <p>Este email ya se encuentra registrado en la base de datos.</p>
                <a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='register.html' role='button'>Volver</a>
                </div>";
} else {    

/*
If the email don't exist, the data from the form is sended to the
database and the account is created
*/
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$celu = $_POST['celu'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

// The password_hash() function convert the password in a hash before send it to the database
$passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Query to send Name, Email and Password hash to the database
$query = "INSERT INTO w_usuarios (nombre, email, celu, pass) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$celu', '$pass')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-4' role='alert'><p>Tu cuenta ha sido creada.</p>
    <a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='index.html' role='button'>Volver</a></div>";       
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }   
}   
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Revisar que los datos se ingresaron correctamente e ingresar a la página, sino un mensaje dice que los datos ingresados son erroneos.(check-login.php)**

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <?php
    // Connection info. file
    include 'conn.php';

    // Connection variables
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    //mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // data sent from form login.html
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    // Query sent to database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email, pass, nombre FROM w_usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");

    /*
            password_Verify() function verify if the password entered by the user
            match the password hash on the database. If everything is OK the session
            is created for one minute. Change 1 on $_SESSION[start] to 5 for a 5 minutes session.
            */
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        //$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        // Variable $row hold the result of the query
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // Variable $hash mantiene el hash de la contraseña en la base de datos
        $hash = $row['pass'];
        if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $hash)) {

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['start'] = time();
            //$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60) ;

            echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-4' role='alert'><strong>Bienvenido!</strong>
                <p><a href='edit-profile.php'>Editar perfil</a></p>
                <p><a href='logout.php'>Cerrar sesión</a></p></div>";

        } else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger mt-4' role='alert'>Email y/o Contraseña son incorrectos!
                <br /><a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='login.html' role='button'>Volver a intentar</a></div>";
        }


    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger mt-4' role='alert'>No se encuentra este email registrado en la base de datos
                <br /><a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='login.html' role='button'>Volver</a></div>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
        </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Conclusión:** Siempre aparece el cartel diciendo "Email y/o Contraseña son incorrectos!" por más que ponga los datos correctos.

Comment: Tienes varios errores de lógica en tu código. Por ejemplo haces `fetch` dos veces de los datos, ¿por qué?  Luego, dentro del `if` que revisa la cantidad de filas deberías meter la verificación, ya que pasas a verificar haya filas o no. Corrige eso y prueba y dinos qué pasa. Y de paso, depura tus variables, trata de mostrar si devuelve filas o no, etc.

Comment: Tienes razón, no se por que hace dos veces `fetch`, puse en comentario `$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`. En cuanto a agregar la verificación en `if (password_verify($pass, $row ['pass'])) {` no se como hacerlo. Perdon por mi ignorancia. Lo que sí logre fue depurar que devuelve las filas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre resolverlo de esta manera (Sacando el hash)

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresar email" name="email" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pass"><b>Contraseña</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu Contraseña" name="pass" required>
      </div>



      <button type="submit">Ingresar</button>
  </form>
```

**checklogin.php - Verifica que los datos coincidan en la base de datos**

```
<?php

include 'conexionlogin.php';

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexión falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";


$result = $conexion->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     }


  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 // if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 
if ($pass==$row['pass']) { 


    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>"; 
    header('Location: http://localhost/my_website/panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario

 } else { 
   echo "Email o Contraseña estan incorrectos.";

   echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion); 
 ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que has hecho. Al renunciar a `password_verify` dejas las contraseñas expuestas, lo cual es un agujero de seguridad. No deberías conformarte con que funcione de esta manera. Habría que ver por qué no funciona con `password_verify`, no renunciar a su uso.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba de este modo, he corregido la lógica que te indicaba en el comentario. Además he agregado un charset adecuado a la conexión, lo cual podría hacer que la comparación falle.

Si no funciona, has de saber que el password debió haber sido hasheado antes de guardarlo en la base de datos con `INSERT`. ¿Podrías confirmarnos que así ha sido?

```
<?php
    // Connection info. file
    include 'conn.php';

    // Connection variables
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // data sent from form login.html
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    // Query sent to database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email, pass, nombre FROM w_usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");

    /*
            password_Verify() function verify if the password entered by the user
            match the password hash on the database. If everything is OK the session
            is created for one minute. Change 1 on $_SESSION[start] to 5 for a 5 minutes session.
            */
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        //$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        // Variable $row hold the result of the query
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // Variable $hash hold the password hash on database
        $hash = $row['pass'];
        if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
            $_SESSION['start'] = time();
            $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60) ;

            echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-4' role='alert'><strong>Bienvenido!</strong> $row[nombre]
                <p><a href='edit-profile.php'>Editar perfil</a></p>
                <p><a href='logout.php'>Cerrar sesión</a></p></div>";

        } else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger mt-4' role='alert'>Email y/o Contraseña son incorrectos!
                <br /><a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='login.html' role='button'>Volver a intentar</a></div>";
        }


    } else {
        echo "No se encontraron filas";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: No funciono. En el formulario de registro existe `$passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` intente lo mismo pero dejando en comentario este código y sigue con el error. También intente con un nuevo usuario sin Hash, sigue pasando lo mismo. El CHARSET yalo había escrito en `<meta charset="utf-8">` pero igual lo intente de tu manera y nada :( . (Igualmente gracias por estar ayudandome)

Comment: @Mr.Name revisa por ejemplo la extensión de la columna en la base de datos, si es muy pequeña puede que el hash esté quedando truncado. Me gustaría ver la forma en que guardas los hash, puede haber error ahí también. Y en cuanto a la codificación, aunque la tengas en el documento, debes ponerla también en la conexión a la base de datos, son configuraciones que trabajan juntas, una no suple a la otra.

Comment: Acabo de extender la columna en la base de datos a 255 caracteres, pero sigue igual. Lo que tengo de hash es todo lo que publique.

Comment: @Mr.Name pero debe haber un código donde insertas la contraseña hasheada, a eso me refiero, si puedes, muestra ese código para revisar si estás guardando el hash correctamente. Si no lo guardas bien, no va a coincidir nunca.

Comment: Ahí cambie en la publicación, en vez de mostrar el formulario del login puse cuando se registra un usuario. Aparte busque en todos los archivos y en estos dos `check-login.php y create-account.php`  son los únicos donde se encuentra un HASH. Será que tengo que crear una tabla que diga hash? Por que para la contraseña solo tengo la columna pass con 255 caracteres disponibles. Igualmente en el Cpanel me muestra cual es la pass y aún así no logro acceder.

Comment: @Mr.Name el código parece correcto. Repasando todo lo dicho antes, lo único por lo que veo que podría estar fallando es que se produzca algún elemento con carácter especial o algo así. En ese sentido deberías trabajar siempre en un entorno `utf8`, tanto en la base de datos (base de datos, tablas y columnas), como en PHP (incluyendo la conexión a la base de datos) como en HTML.